# JPanel paintComponent in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

I found a nice code on the web for drawing a binary tree. I created the binary search tree algorithm for it, now if I pass the root node for the function, it draws out my tree. I want to make it draw step by step, by running it in a thread, and making it sleep after inserting an element. Now the problem is, I guess, the JPanel itself won't be returned until the drawing is complete, so even if it runs on a different thread, it won't be added to my split pane ( I have many sorting algorithms implemented, and already being painted, and all can be accessed from the same tabbed pane. Every tabbed pane contains a split pane and every split pane contains the controlling buttons, and a jpanel, where I draw the algorithms, but the others do not extend from JPanel! ). Could you please help me find a way to run this in a totally different thread then the main program, and be able to see how it draws the tree?

Please do not judge me on this code, I just put it together fast, trying to make it work, this is not the way I code.

```
public class BinaryTree extends JPanel implements Runnable {

private int radius = 20;
private int vGap = 45, hGap = 150;
private int x = 350, y = 25;
private GraphNode root;
private BinarySearchTreeSort binaryTreeSort;
private int latency = 270;
private boolean isManual = false;

//Stores the sorting algorithm's instance
public BinaryTree(BinarySearchTreeSort binaryTreeSort) {
    this.binaryTreeSort = binaryTreeSort;
}

@Override
public void run() {
//Maybe i should put here the paintComponent somehow???
    root = binaryTreeSort.binaryTreeSort();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
    displayTree(g, root, x, y, hGap);
}

private void displayTree(Graphics g, GraphNode root, int x, int y, int hGap) {
    // Display the root  
    while (!isStarted) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BinaryTreeFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

    if (root.getValue() != 0) {
        g.drawString(root.getValue() + "", x - 13, y + 4);

    }

    sleep();

    if (root.getLeftChild() != null) {
        // Draw a line to the left node  
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        leftChild(g, x - hGap, y + vGap, x, y);
        //Draw the left subtree   
        displayTree(g, root.getLeftChild(), x - hGap, y + vGap, hGap / 2);
    }

    if (root.getRightChild() != null) {
        // Draw a line to the right node  
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        rightChild(g, x + hGap, y + vGap, x, y);
        // Draw the right subtree recursively  
        displayTree(g, root.getRightChild(), x + hGap, y + vGap, hGap / 2);
    }

}

/* Draw left child */
private void leftChild(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    double d = Math.sqrt(vGap * vGap + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));
    int x11 = (int) (x1 + radius * (x2 - x1) / d);
    int y11 = (int) (y1 - radius * vGap / d);
    int x21 = (int) (x2 - radius * (x2 - x1) / d);
    int y21 = (int) (y2 + radius * vGap / d);
    g.drawLine(x11, y11, x21, y21);

    //g.drawString("0", ((x21 + x11) - 20) / 2, (y21 + y11) / 2);
}

/*Draw right child */
private void rightChild(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    double d = Math.sqrt(vGap * vGap + (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1));
    int x11 = (int) (x1 - radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
    int y11 = (int) (y1 - radius * vGap / d);
    int x21 = (int) (x2 + radius * (x1 - x2) / d);
    int y21 = (int) (y2 + radius * vGap / d);
    g.drawLine(x11, y11, x21, y21);

    //g.drawString("1", (x21 + x11) / 2, (y21 + y11) / 2);
}

public void sleep() {
    if (!isManual) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(latency);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BinaryTree.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this idea is wrong for Java >1.4, there are one way to test for isEventDisp...., on false to paintImmediatelly on true repaint(int, x, x, x) clip only, recrusivelly

Comment: 1) Read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). 2) invoke `super.paintComponent()` before custom paintings. 3) Seems you need to use `SwingWorker` or `ExecutorService` for background work without blocking `EDT` for repainting.

Comment: never-ever sleep the EDT (particularly not in the paint cycle)! Instead, use some logic to un/mark nodes as "visible" (or some other property of the tree state) and then call repaint after each step

Comment: just thinking out loud (as in a brainstorm-session), maybe you could create the tree, but not paint it. And then paint a new tree, only containing the root-folder. Then add one by one, the subfolders/files to this tree, and do a repaint and sleep after every 'add'.

So you use the first tree, to run over, and create the new tree, step by step, based on the first.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i will try them when ill get home.